# Split ssldump output into multiple files for every incoming connection

Tags: files, io-redirection, ssl

I am capturing SSL Handshake data using ssldump on the terminal, and using the command

```
sudo ssldump -i enp0s8 -a -A -H -n -x > new_trace
```

to output it into a single file. Currently, the output looks like the output quoted below. The part that is relevant to my question is that every time a new connection comes in, there is a new line that looks like

```
New TCP connection #2: 192.168.33.1(57380) <-> 192.168.33.10(443)
```

What I want to be able to do is to capture the output of ssldump in a separate file for each connection. Is it something that is possible? For example, can I somehow create a new file each time a `New TCP connection` string is seen?

```
New TCP connection #1: 192.168.33.1(57378) <-> 192.168.33.10(443)
1 1  0.0006 (0.0006)  C>SV3.1(512)  Handshake
      ClientHello
        Version 3.3 
        random[32]=
          b4 b0 59 7b bb 3c aa e1 04 50 17 bd 8a 71 f0 30 
          54 ed 7f 4c 83 de b3 48 9b 32 9d 0b a3 5d 2a 0c 
        resume [32]=
          8a b5 d0 1f 2d b3 f0 c5 7a 19 b9 f3 b8 b4 f2 f5 
          7c a2 fc 92 29 ee 63 dc a3 ca fa 1f 31 45 6c 69 
        cipher suites
        Unknown value 0xbaba
        Unknown value 0x1301
        Unknown value 0x1302
        Unknown value 0x1303
        Unknown value 0xc02b
        Unknown value 0xc02f
        Unknown value 0xc02c
        Unknown value 0xc030
        Unknown value 0xcca9
        Unknown value 0xcca8
        Unknown value 0xc013
        Unknown value 0xc014
        Unknown value 0x9c
        Unknown value 0x9d
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        compression methods
                  NULL
Packet data[517]=
  16 03 01 02 00 01 00 01 fc 03 03 b4 b0 59 7b bb 
  3c aa e1 04 50 17 bd 8a 71 f0 30 54 ed 7f 4c 83 
  de b3 48 9b 32 9d 0b a3 5d 2a 0c 20 8a b5 d0 1f 
  2d b3 f0 c5 7a 19 b9 f3 b8 b4 f2 f5 7c a2 fc 92 
  29 ee 63 dc a3 ca fa 1f 31 45 6c 69 00 22 ba ba 
  13 01 13 02 13 03 c0 2b c0 2f c0 2c c0 30 cc a9 
  cc a8 c0 13 c0 14 00 9c 00 9d 00 2f 00 35 00 0a 
  01 00 01 91 ba ba 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 16 00 00 
  13 74 69 6d 65 32 2e 73 65 63 75 72 65 70 6b 69 
  2e 6f 72 67 00 17 00 00 ff 01 00 01 00 00 0a 00 
  0a 00 08 fa fa 00 1d 00 17 00 18 00 0b 00 02 01 
  00 00 23 00 00 00 10 00 0e 00 0c 02 68 32 08 68 
  74 74 70 2f 31 2e 31 00 05 00 05 01 00 00 00 00 
  00 0d 00 14 00 12 04 03 08 04 04 01 05 03 08 05 
  05 01 08 06 06 01 02 01 00 12 00 00 00 33 00 2b 
  00 29 fa fa 00 01 00 00 1d 00 20 b2 35 fc 32 96 
  1b ce 5b c1 eb 3c e0 36 fe 89 6e 45 ec 91 02 16 
  6a 00 8b c5 75 23 4a d9 52 76 48 00 2d 00 02 01 
  01 00 2b 00 0b 0a aa aa 03 04 03 03 03 02 03 01 
  00 1b 00 03 02 00 02 3a 3a 00 01 00 00 15 00 c5 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  00 00 00 00 00 


1 2  0.0028 (0.0021)  S>CV3.3(84)  Handshake
      ServerHello
        Version 3.3 
        random[32]=
          67 47 65 0a c8 d5 96 78 22 16 2f 5e 68 e2 2f 67 
          51 17 37 e7 e7 0a ce 06 10 1b 6d 63 5d c6 0c 0b 
        session_id[0]=

        cipherSuite         Unknown value 0xc030
        compressionMethod                   NULL
Packet data[89]=
  16 03 03 00 54 02 00 00 50 03 03 67 47 65 0a c8 
  d5 96 78 22 16 2f 5e 68 e2 2f 67 51 17 37 e7 e7 
  0a ce 06 10 1b 6d 63 5d c6 0c 0b 00 c0 30 00 00 
  28 ff 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 00 04 03 00 
  01 02 00 23 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 10 00 0b 00 09 
  08 68 74 74 70 2f 31 2e 31 


1 3  0.0028 (0.0000)  S>CV3.3(934)  Handshake
      Certificate
Packet data[939]=
  16 03 03 03 a6 0b 00 03 a2 00 03 9f 00 03 9c 30 
  82 03 98 30 82 02 80 a0 03 02 01 02 02 09 01 62 
  56 fb c9 3c e9 65 18 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 
  0d 01 01 0b 05 00 30 54 31 21 30 1f 06 03 55 04 
  03 0c 18 4e 6f 72 74 68 65 61 73 74 65 72 6e 20 
  53 53 4c 20 54 65 73 74 20 43 41 31 15 30 13 06 
  03 55 04 0a 0c 0c 4e 6f 72 74 68 65 61 73 74 65 
  72 6e 31 18 30 16 06 03 55 04 0b 0c 0f 53 53 4c 
  20 43 6c 6f 63 6b 20 53 6b 65 77 73 30 1e 17 0d 
  31 36 30 34 31 30 32 31 30 34 32 34 5a 17 0d 31 
  39 30 34 31 30 32 31 30 35 32 38 5a 30 60 31 0b 
  30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 55 53 31 0b 30 09 06 
  03 55 04 08 0c 02 4d 41 31 0f 30 0d 06 03 55 04 
  07 0c 06 42 6f 73 74 6f 6e 31 15 30 13 06 03 55 
  04 0a 0c 0c 4e 6f 72 74 68 65 61 73 74 65 72 6e 
  31 1c 30 1a 06 03 55 04 03 0c 13 74 69 6d 65 32 
  2e 73 65 63 75 72 65 70 6b 69 2e 6f 72 67 30 82 
  01 22 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01 05 
  00 03 82 01 0f 00 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 d5 
  a5 51 9d 89 b2 cf 1d 8b 9d 36 69 47 e3 f8 42 ff 
  4f 9a fb 4e 3a 0b 7a 67 22 de d8 7e 32 22 ff 51 
  0f 23 c1 e8 16 c4 4a 07 0f c1 b2 bc 5e 17 f4 b7 
  ce d7 11 9e a3 79 33 e7 28 5c 4b 0e b0 6b a4 a9 
  4d 8a ca 24 54 c0 f4 ca f5 0b 04 5b 0f 15 d8 c5 
  ee 8a 6c 3f 91 a9 d9 6c 15 78 c5 d0 13 0f 6b af 
  1b 6c 32 f2 30 7d f9 2e 7a 9e 78 7f 20 68 66 e3 
  6d 15 52 87 e9 23 f2 5c 3a c6 81 2a 7e 29 ea 6f 
  6a b0 51 2e 94 84 ae be 70 8e 9e cc 9c 91 55 ea 
  ed 98 26 80 2b b2 7b d3 ad c7 b5 c3 da 8e 68 8d 
  45 ba 5a 24 e2 56 7f 0c 72 3d 48 98 43 2e fb bc 
  11 26 db b9 c1 8d a8 01 77 67 76 ef 48 a1 35 74 
  80 05 62 2c b6 c8 44 ac b5 44 59 e6 b2 e6 0d 4b 
  bb 15 b2 83 86 c4 26 bc e1 80 72 65 79 11 a4 f3 
  c5 21 42 03 b3 f1 73 ea 9f 8b 4a dd 6c 1d 8a bb 
  bc b1 5a 6a 7f 85 c0 45 80 82 8a 50 3d 71 13 02 
  03 01 00 01 a3 61 30 5f 30 0e 06 03 55 1d 0f 01 
  01 ff 04 04 03 02 05 e0 30 0c 06 03 55 1d 13 01 
  01 ff 04 02 30 00 30 1f 06 03 55 1d 23 04 18 30 
  16 80 14 06 2d f4 43 60 76 97 3b 03 6e e2 28 e6 
  ba b2 ab e2 f0 f3 4d 30 1e 06 03 55 1d 11 04 17 
  30 15 82 13 74 69 6d 65 32 2e 73 65 63 75 72 65 
  70 6b 69 2e 6f 72 67 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 
  0d 01 01 0b 05 00 03 82 01 01 00 40 41 42 54 2c 
  5b ce af dd ea 4c a6 43 43 72 70 bd 22 61 69 51 
  1d 07 0c 60 ce 33 16 25 03 a4 03 67 fb c7 5c eb 
  4c 55 de c3 33 af 61 97 24 4e 5a 5a b6 17 df 39 
  99 3b 1f 45 88 6d 2b e8 0e c1 12 38 40 44 44 6b 
  5c 56 1c f6 d8 6d 2a 44 27 24 32 ce a4 29 49 12 
  0a 45 df b8 88 55 67 11 c4 3b af d7 01 b6 6e 6c 
  53 f3 12 0c b1 7f 16 d2 14 33 bd 9d cb 57 21 40 
  eb 49 fe a8 ea a1 e2 93 40 93 62 54 a1 9d 37 1b 
  da 54 35 ab e6 b0 b8 bc 3f fb b9 ae c3 a5 5c 44 
  50 e4 6c e5 96 a3 a9 5a fc d0 fe 9d 17 b2 4e b4 
  12 84 1c 1f f9 f7 02 61 35 fa 06 8f 83 69 0a a5 
  bd 89 02 d2 2c 76 4d 95 68 f7 89 af 02 1c 57 e5 
  2c 31 62 3f e3 4e 26 55 39 ec aa 2c 76 a5 e0 f9 
  01 a3 42 c4 69 89 d2 81 6a 63 3e fa a2 4c 9c b1 
  f6 f3 5f e1 5f b0 08 e4 29 ca e7 39 ba 12 b2 ab 
  31 47 5c ff e6 d0 0e 47 35 2b bb 


1 4  0.0028 (0.0000)  S>CV3.3(300)  Handshake
      ServerKeyExchange
Packet data[305]=
  16 03 03 01 2c 0c 00 01 28 03 00 1d 20 df 4d 5e 
  c0 1d d2 c9 6c 56 9f e8 35 d2 be 70 12 99 4f 41 
  b5 88 d9 f0 a9 35 61 eb c2 bb 1f 8e 2c 06 01 01 
  00 40 90 ec e2 fa 4f e7 36 8a 53 0e 68 89 15 8a 
  79 10 a1 14 55 ce c0 7c 4f d7 c7 46 9e 29 87 bc 
  34 29 70 1c 2e 43 bf 0a fb 53 6a 13 a6 5c 74 3b 
  d6 99 fa 40 34 c4 10 a1 78 6c 62 8c e2 51 e8 a5 
  b8 eb 80 c5 d3 06 47 ce 25 10 df f3 63 e1 bb 68 
  66 40 2c 89 cb 75 8a 09 0a 79 aa 88 ef 19 58 30 
  99 0e 05 aa 23 14 93 52 87 17 39 92 6d 01 4a 09 
  d1 b0 6d fe 37 59 56 f0 f4 8d 52 b1 0e 10 ec 1c 
  7d 44 1d 68 4c b8 be 9b 47 85 26 fc cc 6d 5e d9 
  51 1a b3 2f 75 de 90 a3 5d f1 9c 6b eb ad 8e cf 
  4b a3 41 6f d3 91 ef 76 e6 f1 52 f3 c9 75 b5 e9 
  0c ed f7 aa 8d dd f2 3f 79 6e e9 f3 ba 93 3d 68 
  fc d0 07 58 a5 f4 3f 4e 76 bb 1f 5d 27 51 fd 38 
  a7 49 7f de 6c 8e 63 7d f4 52 5a 7e 27 63 b7 d8 
  55 3f 4a 39 63 e3 88 40 13 84 c0 87 53 d7 26 44 
  70 15 70 ed 6a 85 b3 82 90 47 48 84 94 fe 9e cc 
  19 


1 5  0.0028 (0.0000)  S>CV3.3(4)  Handshake
      ServerHelloDone
Packet data[9]=
  16 03 03 00 04 0e 00 00 00 


1 6  0.0038 (0.0009)  C>SV3.3(37)  Handshake
      ClientKeyExchange
Packet data[42]=
  16 03 03 00 25 10 00 00 21 20 c2 34 95 bd d9 fa 
  fe 7a 52 aa 4c 44 4b f6 f0 b1 4a be f7 c7 68 6c 
  e8 75 17 9b ed cc ec b7 5c 11 


1 7  0.0038 (0.0000)  C>SV3.3(1)  ChangeCipherSpec
Packet data[6]=
  14 03 03 00 01 01 


1 8  0.0038 (0.0000)  C>SV3.3(40)  Handshake
Packet data[45]=
  16 03 03 00 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 98 a8 
  28 a6 35 4f 20 e8 e2 ca ee fb d6 58 95 ca 31 ea 
  86 5c c2 04 6c 35 d9 ba bd a0 27 fa 8a 


1    0.0040 (0.0002)  C>S  TCP FIN
1 9  0.0045 (0.0005)  S>CV3.3(218)  Handshake
Packet data[223]=
  16 03 03 00 da 04 00 00 d6 00 00 01 2c 00 d0 e4 
  ef 74 bb 05 44 68 1c 3a b7 45 c1 bd 87 28 92 e3 
  6e ba db a1 58 38 f2 d4 e4 ce fc 68 d9 25 b3 c4 
  ed ea 33 71 6a ac 42 74 6d 50 f0 66 92 bd 7f d2 
  78 a2 3e 33 0d 02 3b f1 0d b2 04 6a 99 19 15 46 
  8d 0d 78 c9 6f 05 bd 00 e5 3a 65 34 7b 67 d1 8e 
  ee 60 77 dc 61 51 be 27 6d 9f e1 58 b4 13 26 c0 
  ad 31 88 a8 66 30 bb 54 fb ba b8 f9 a4 5a 00 ca 
  de 18 3c 8d ae 3a 31 b1 a3 2d 62 44 1a 3a 79 35 
  a8 22 86 ae 5d f5 55 1b d0 43 08 7c bf 38 72 b0 
  97 79 43 aa 5d ef 7c 36 48 63 ac a9 00 d6 7d d9 
  be b6 51 c9 c1 0c 26 a8 84 c9 38 95 ea e1 eb 70 
  13 58 dd db 14 90 42 33 46 42 36 3c bd ab 66 44 
  c5 e1 11 e7 5c 43 a5 06 33 7d 80 ea 8a b5 b1 


1 10 0.0045 (0.0000)  S>CV3.3(1)  ChangeCipherSpec
Packet data[6]=
  14 03 03 00 01 01 


1 11 0.0045 (0.0000)  S>CV3.3(40)  Handshake
Packet data[45]=
  16 03 03 00 28 1f 9d ba 7d 2f 5e b5 b2 65 eb 93 
  85 64 58 29 17 a0 23 8d d0 db ab 99 be ab d4 e7 
  f8 6c 0b 0d f6 0e 6d 1f d6 d4 e4 1d 5d 


1    0.0047 (0.0001)  S>C  TCP FIN
New TCP connection #2: 192.168.33.1(57380) <-> 192.168.33.10(443)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csplit` to split into separate files.

```
sudo ssldump -i enp0s8 -a -A -H -n -x | csplit - '/^New TCP connection/'
```

This will split the input into up to 100 files, named `xx00` up to `xx99`.

You can set the prefix (default `xx`) to something else using the `--prefix=somethingelse` option.

The numer of digits used to count the files (default 2) can be set with `--digits=X`.

You may need to use the `--keep-files` option if `csplit` removes the generated files when you stop the process (it may interpret the interrupt as a failure).